# CentOS 6: Transaction Check Error to install php-gd

Tags: php, centos6, php-gd

I have a VPS with CentOS 6.8 in which I am trying to install PhP GD. I have tried `sudo yum install php-gd`, as I installed others libraries. When I do this, I get the following:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.daniel-jost.net
 * epel: mirror.23media.de
 * extras: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
 * ius: lon.mirror.rackspace.com
 * remi-php55: rpms.remirepo.net
 * remi-safe: rpms.remirepo.net
 * updates: mirror.23media.de
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.5.38-7.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gd-last.x86_64 0:2.2.4-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.5()(64bit) for package: gd-last-2.2.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libwebp.x86_64 0:0.4.3-3.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===========================================================================================
 Package           Arch             Version                     Repository            Size
===========================================================================================
Installing:
 php-gd            x86_64           5.5.38-7.el6.remi           remi-php55            78 k
Installing for dependencies:
 gd-last           x86_64           2.2.4-1.el6.remi            remi-safe            126 k
 libwebp           x86_64           0.4.3-3.el6                 epel                 210 k

Transaction Summary
===========================================================================================
Install       3 Package(s)

Total size: 415 k
Installed size: 1.3 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test

Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libgd.so.3 from install of gd-last-2.2.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package gd-2.1.0-1.el6.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

A list of all the repositories you can see below the line `"Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile"`

It the same mistake I get when trying to install: `yum install php-tcpdf`. 
As I understood this is a problem in `gd-last`. But I don't understand how to solve this problem.

Any idea on what can I do to install Php-Gd and solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dependence error
try deleting it if u can:

> yum remove gd-2.1.0-1.el6.x86_64

and then try to install it again.

Comment: I uninstalled and re-installed GD library.
After that, the problem was resolved
**Thank you!**

Comment: gd-last is designed to be install beside system gd-2.0.35, no idea where this gd-2.1.0 comes from.

Comment: I think u added some external repos, this sometimes causes thoose kind of problems, because external repos sometimes doesnt care about some dependences from the oficial repos, or the simpli the external repos are outdated and the packets ask for outdated packets too,